# TCL - SQLite how to obtain the 32bit Libs (the TCL part, not the sqlite dll itself)

Tags: sqlite, tcl, 32-bit

I have a problem with obtaining the TCL Librarys for SQLite3 for 32 bit.

The problem is not the DLLs from SQLite itself. They're still offered, but what I'm missing is a wrapper to it for TCL.

I need to handle both the 64 bit and the 32 bit Versions of ActiveTCL. Under 64 bit there is no problem, runs like a breeze. Under 32 bit I just don't get it to work. I have the SQLite3 DLLs into the Lib dir, but whenever I try a package require of it, I receive a "sqlite_init" not found.

From what I found out out by googling this topic, it seems, I'm missing a wrapper dll that handles the communication between TCL and SQLite. Well, these wrappers are not found anymore in their binary version, at least not by me :). Sometimes you'll find some source-repositories to make one on your own. Problem is, modern Compilers like VC community 2022 seem to not even handle the old make system (at least it seems to me this way).

Is there any help? binaries? Whatever is requirered to solve this problem? :)

Any help highly appreciated. Thankls.

What I tried: Finding any binary wrapper on the net to no avail. Searching for the source of the problem with any informtion I could get a hold on to no avail.
Right now I'm helpless with that.

Comment: There isn't a wrapper for Tcl. The SQLite library can be compiled with the Tcl interface enabled, which is what you need. If you already have a Tcl build environment, you can do it yourself. See the [docs](https://sqlite.org/howtocompile.html#compiling_the_tcl_interface)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Directly from the link you posted: 
"Building shared libraries for Mac OS X and Windows is not nearly so simple, unfortunately. For those platforms it is best to use the configure script and makefile that is included with the TEA tarball."
And that seems to be part of my problem. I need that for windows. Next problem is, the make process is still in its ages, while, for instance, the tools grew 'younger'.

Comment: I used to work with Visual studio 12 Years ago. There it had a regular make, as we are used to it. Look at that now. If it has no .sln at least you're lost. At least I am.
Is there a way, or at least a good description, that helps in building these things nowadays?
Seems like an easy task, but I admit, I'm completeley lost here. Seems there is no easy "make xyz" here for me.

Comment: probably solved!
In a sort of unpleasant thread I found a possible solution right before the thread ends ( [link](https://comp.lang.tcl.narkive.com/FcgcRxNb/couldn-t-find-procedure-sqlite3-init) )
it was the TCL-statement "teacup install sqlite3"

right after I finally did receive the Version number of the lib after the package require!
I admit, I never even heard of teacup beforehand, but right now I'm just happy with it :)